# KVM Networking - Multiple LANs

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, cisco-asa

I'm trying to set up some virtual servers with kvm and am struggling to work out what to do regards the network config. Currently I have 10 dedicated servers behind a firewall (asa 5505) - 2 of these dedicated servers I'd like to use as kvm hosts, each hosting 5 VMs.

In the past I've followed tutorials instrusting me to create a bridge (br0) to eth0 on the kvm host allowing them to get onto the network configured on the firewall. This brings me to my issue in that the 'inside' interface on the firewall has network/subnet of x.x.x.x/28 which doesn't provide enough ip's for the 10 dedicated + 10 virtual servers I'll have.

I suppose my question is what are my options and how could they be configured? One option would be to change the subnet mask however this will mean changing the site-site VPNs configured on the firewall and I'm very reluctant to do this.

I'm not sure if I should complicate things at this stage but:

- some of the VMs need public IPs (which are the x.x.x.x addresses)
- VM's on dedicated server 1 need to be able to talk to VMs on dedicated server 2

Comment: Contact your upstream provider and get more IP addresses, and some IPv6 while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set up [NAT routing](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#NAT_forwarding_.28aka_.22virtual_networks.22.29) rather than bridged routing on your KVM host.  However, this creates some issues you may need to address if you need inbound connectivity to guest VMs behind the NAT. You can set up rules on the KVM host to port-forward specific inbound traffic to specified guests, but (as with most NAT) unless you have some kind of load-balancing or other high-level traffic management layer, a port can only be forwarded to one guest.

Also, if you can segregate the VMs allocated to each host based on which other VMs they need to talk to, you may be able to get away with NAT without port-forwarding.

With all that said, if it were me and I controlled the address space I'd just change the subnet, adjust the VPN routing as needed, and use bridged networking.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. From what you say it sounds like it wouldn't be possible to have VM1 on Host1 with ip 192.168.122.101 talk directly to VM2 on Host2 with ip 192.168.122.102 without the use of port forwarding (or high-level traffic mgmt), is that right? My plan was to have one of the dedicated servers as a mysql vm host and the other as the web app vm host, so segregation would be tricky

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to bridges, and (possibly) a separate VLAN for internal traffic, with an internal NAT/router to take care of NAT to the "inside" network and onwards.

A nicer solution would be to simply increase the subnet size of "inside"